# Does TG prove that ZFC2 has a model?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Does TG ([Tarski-Grothendieck Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski-Grothendieck_set_theory)) prove that ZFC2 (second-order ZFC) has a model? Does it at least prove the consistency of ZFC2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gathering two bits from the Wikipedia entries:

> It is a non-conservative extension of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory (ZFC) and is distinguished from other axiomatic set theories by the inclusion of Tarski's axiom which states that for each set there is a Grothendieck universe it belongs to (see below).
>
> Tarski's axiom implies the existence of inaccessible cardinals, providing a richer ontology than that of conventional set theories such as ZFC. (Wikipedia, [Tarski–Grothendieck set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski-Grothendieck_set_theory))

And in turn

> Secondly, under ZFC it can be shown that $\kappa$ is inaccessible if and only if $(V_\kappa,\in)$ is a model of second order ZFC. (Wikipedia, [Inaccessible cardinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal))

So the answer is indeed positive.